# How to generate addition table for ring $\mathbb Z_{15}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields

How do I generate an addition table for ring `R` such that

$R = \mathbb{Z}_{15}$

or generally speaking, how to generate an addition table for any polynomial ring `R`?

I tried following `Inactive` notation as mentioned [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/inactive-objects/make-addition-and-multiplication-tables.html), but it is generating blank output.

I have tried evaluating the following snippet

```
   (plus = Table[Inactive[Plus][a, b] == mod[a + b, 15] {a, 15}, {b,15}]) // TableForm
```

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried?

Comment: I have edited the question and added my snippet

Comment: Two things: you're missing a comma, and `Mod` must be capitalized.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I restarted Mathematica and made the changes you suggested!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question in case someone stumbles upon this. My coding snippet was missing comma and had incorrect `Mod` function keyword.

```
(plus = Table[Inactive[Plus][a, b] == Mod[a + b, 15], {a, 15}, {b, 15}]) // TableForm
```

Comment: Rings have two operations. What about the multiplicative structure?