# How to generate addition table for $GF(2)[x] \mod x^3 + 1 = 0$

Tags: polynomials, group-theory, finite-fields

I have been playing with Mathematica for a while. I tried generating addition table for a simple ring $R$ such that $R = \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ as asked in my last [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182598/how-to-generate-addition-table-for-ring-z15).

However, I am completely clueless while generating such tables for polynomial rings.

E.g. $R = GF(2)[x]\mod x^3 + 1 = 0$

How do I represent Polynomial rings in Mathematica? I know that the table will have 8 elements in the above ring written as follows

$0, 1, x, x + 1, x^2, x^2 + 1, x^2 + x, x^2 + x + 1$

But I am clueless on how to add these elements in Mathematica. E.g. $1 + (x+1)$.

Comment: Can you make PolynomialMod or PolynomialQuotientRemainder do waht you are looking for? For instance: PolynomialMod[(x + 1) + 1, {x^3 + 1, 2}]

Comment: I tried doing `PolynomialMod` but I am not sure it's working. 

`PolynomialMod[(x^2 + x) * (x + 1), 2]` is evaluating to `x + x^3`.

Edit: I forgot to mod by `x^3 + 1`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like PolynomialMod is what you are looking for. The second argument contains the polynomial and the field size, hence:

```
PolynomialMod[(x^2 + x)*(x + 1), {x^3 + 1, 2}]
1 + x

PolynomialMod[1+(x + 1), {x^3 + 1, 2}]
x
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! Any pointers on how to create a table (of 64 entries) for the all the elements?

Comment: I got it. 
`factors = {0, 1, x, x + 1, x^2, x^2 + 1, x^2 + x, x^2 + x + 1}`
`Table[PolynomialMod[a * b, {x^3 + 1, 2}], {a,  factors}, {b, 
   factors}] // TableForm`